Breezing Forms reCAPTCHA doesn't display with JCH enabled - how to fix?
A combination of JCH Optimize combining of JS files and moving them to the bottom and Breezing Forms with reCAPTCHA enabled results in invisible captcha, inability to send the form and No reCAPTCHA clients exist. error in the console.
How to make reCAPTCHA work with JCH, without disabling it on pages with forms?

In Global Configuration -> JCH Optimize -> JavaScript -> Exclude JavaScript files include this file:
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js

That prevents the form from trying to load reCAPTCHA before that script loads.

Please Accept your answer as the correct solution.
